# How to return null record with header after fail insert?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm writing a stored procedure and I encountered an issue with return records after insert.

I know we can use `row_count` to know if the insert was successful or not.

And my goal is:

1. If it success, return this record that recently insert.
2. It it fail, return null object with header.

Something like that:

**Success**:

The returned values of my stored procedure:

```
|id     |release   |runtime  |
|-------|----------|---------|
|01     |1-May-29  |62 min   |
```

And if it fails

```
|id     |release   |runtime  |
|-------|----------|---------|
|       |          |         |
```

For 1 it's easy, but I don't know how make it work with 2.

I also use transaction with commit to roll back if it can't insert.

Comment: Please show us your current queries you tried

Answer (score 0):

Using OUTPUT into clause.

```html
CREATE PROCEDURE #temp_sp 
 @id INT
 ,@name VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
 CREATE TABLE #real_table (
  id INT
  ,NAME VARCHAR(50)
  )

 CREATE TABLE #temp_insert (
  id INT
  ,NAME VARCHAR(50)
  )

 INSERT INTO #real_table
 OUTPUT inserted.id
  ,inserted.NAME
 INTO #temp_insert
 VALUES (
  @id
  ,@name
  )

 SELECT id
  ,NAME
 FROM #temp_insert
END

--TEST EXEC
EXEC #temp_sp 1,'A'
EXEC #temp_sp NULL,NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delimiter $$
create procedure proc(_id int, _release datetime, _runtime varchar(60))
begin
    declare success int;
    .... /** here goes INSERT statement */
    select row_count() into success;
    if (success > 0) then
       select _id as id, _release as 'release', _runtime as runtime;
    else
       select null as id, null as 'release', null as runtime;
    end if;   
end$$
delimiter;
```

Notice that `release` is [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) in MySQL, that's why it is written as varchar in `SELECT`. In case that `id` is not known beforehand (i.e. you are using `AUTOINCREMENT`), then use `last_insert_id()` in the `SELECT`.

In case that you don't want to return record with null values in case of failure, but empty set, then just use the following:

```
declare last_id int;
set last_id = -1; /** or some other value that cannot exist in the table */
..
if (success > 0) then
    set last_id = last_insert_id();
end if;
..
SELECT id, release, runtime FROM table_name WHERE id = last_id;
```

Comment: I also think to your first solution with select null as ... But my table have too much columns, and I just want to select *. If i work as your suggest It make loss of time. For your second solution with id=_id. Actually the input of my store proc not have information of _id. My _id is auto generate id in mysql.

Comment: @JameH Try to avoid `select *` in your queries, it is always better to enumerate columns because when you add new columns in the future the other side that deals with the result gets confused. Updated the answer to reflect autoincrement.

Comment: @JameH Did it help?